# ansi-terminal: unexpected behavior on Windows

Tags: linux, windows, haskell, ansi-escape

I'm experimenting with [ansi-terminal](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ansi-terminal-0.6.1.1) in Haskell and seem to be having trouble with the behavior on Windows as compared to Linux. On Linux, I get a blue "@" which I can move around with wasd keys (as expected), and can quit by pressing any other key. On windows, I just get a white "@" that doesn't move, and can't move the character at all.

How can I duplicate Linux behavior in Windows?

A few notes:

- By Windows, I mean that I compiled and ran under wine
- cabal 1.18.0.3
- ghc 7.6.3
- installed ansi-terminal by 'wine cabal install'
- I'd prefer not to have to use ncurses (hscurses) if possible

**update:** The minimal failing code is:

```
import System.Console.ANSI

main :: IO ()
main = do
    clearScreen
    setCursorPosition 0 0
    setSGR [SetColor Foreground Vivid Blue]
    putStrLn "@"
    setSGR [Reset]
```

On Linux, this does the "right" thing in that a blue "@" is printed. Under wine, I see no changes. I'm hoping that this is just a peculiarity of wine and not Windows, as I don't have access to a Windows box to try this on.

The *(original)* code I tried:

```
module Main where

import Data.Monoid 
import Control.Monad (unless)
import System.Console.ANSI
import System.IO

-- | thin wrapper around ansi-terminal's API ------------------------------
reset :: IO ()
reset = hSetSGR stdout [Reset]

bold :: [SGR]
bold = [SetConsoleIntensity BoldIntensity]

normal :: [SGR]
normal = [SetConsoleIntensity NormalIntensity]

background :: ColorIntensity -> Color -> [SGR]
background i c = [SetColor Background i c]

foreground :: ColorIntensity -> Color -> [SGR]
foreground i c = [SetColor Foreground i c]

swap :: [SGR]
swap = [SetSwapForegroundBackground True]

underline :: [SGR]
underline = [SetUnderlining SingleUnderline]

noUnderline :: [SGR]
noUnderline = [SetUnderlining NoUnderline]


-- Main -------------------------------------------------------------------
initTerminal :: IO ()
initTerminal = do
    hSetEcho stdin False
    mapM_ (`hSetBuffering` NoBuffering) [stdin, stdout]
    hideCursor
    hSetTitle stdout "Functional Wizardry: The Roguelike"

run :: Int -> Int -> IO ()
run x y = do
    hClearScreen stdout
    hSetCursorPosition stdout x y
    setSGR $ bold <> foreground Vivid Blue
    putStr "@"
    (x', y') <- getInput

    unless ((x', y') == (-1, -1)) $ run (x + x') (y + y')


getInput :: IO (Int, Int)
getInput = do
    char <- getChar
    case char of
        'a' -> return (0, -1)
        'd' -> return (0, 1)
        'w' -> return (1, 0)
        's' -> return (-1, 0)
        _ -> do
            hClearScreen stdout
            hSetCursorPosition stdout 0 0
            return (-1, -1)


main :: IO ()
main = do
    initTerminal
    run 0 0
    reset
```

Comment: It'd help if you reduced this code to a minimal example which behaves differently on Linux vs on Windows.

Comment: Don't know how I missed your comment Roman, I'll do that here shortly.

Comment: Works as expected on Windows 7. Probably a wine bug.

Comment: Awesome! Roman, do the arrow keys allow you to move the cursor in the original version?

Answer (score 3):

Does your Windows console support ANSI? Character colour and cursor positioning in ANSI terminals is done by streaming specific ESC-sequences (going back in time to VT-100 DEC terminal, and some possibly going way further back). This requires exposure of the console as a streaming device. The last time I tried to use ANSI codes supported by xterm, it didn't work on Windows and I had to write a native library to expose access to Windows console API. This is because the API that I could find exposed Windows console as opaque API with no streaming behaviour.

Caveat: I tried that in Java, but unless Haskell `ansi-terminal` library does some platform-specific wizardry instead of plain ANSI ESC-sequences, it will fail in the same way.

Try to `run 20 20` from the start - do you get `@` at 20,20, or still 0,0? If it is still 0,0, it must be a problem with ANSI support by Windows console. I don't know if that can be configured to support ANSI.

Comment: As far as I understand (I'm at work, so I'll have to get the reference later), ansi-terminal calls console functions directly for Windows, merely emulating the ansi code interface. **update:** here's the reference: https://github.com/feuerbach/ansi-terminal/tree/master/System/Console/ANSI/Windows

Comment: Many years ago, it was possible to configure support for ANSI escape sequences in MS DOS by setting up the ANSI.SYS driver (probably in CONFIG.SYS, but my memory has limits). I'm pretty sure that worked in 16-bit Windows and Windows 95/98 too. I don't think I've ever seen escape sequences used in XP onwards and I don't even know if it's possible. There was certainly a perception that terminal emulation was an inefficient and limited legacy trick even back in the DOS days, though the alternative was to get direct access to screen memory or use a non-portable library that did that for you.